# "Innovare" senza una connotazione positiva

Tags: synonym

Il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/innovare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) come sinonimi di *innovare* mi dà:

> ammodernare, modernizzare, riformare, rimodernare, rinnovare, svecchiare

o ancora, con differente segno grafico

> modificare, variare

Il primo gruppo di sinonimi condivide con *innovare* la connotazione positiva che la nostra cultura dà al NUOVO.

Il secondo gruppo stempera troppo il significato di *innovare* ed entrambi i termini mi sembrano assai blandi.

Come posso nominare delle innovazioni con una forte connotazione negativa?

Comment: @abarisone Ma allora correggi anche il _da_ nella prima riga :-)

Comment: Giusta osservazione, me l'ero perso ;-))

Comment: Lo metto in un commento perché le domande è meglio che siano fattuali… esempi di _"innovazioni con una forte connotazione negativa"_  sono il nostro pane quotidiano.

Comment: Se per innovazione si intende in generale una novità che porta un miglioramento allora si potrebbero usare i sinonimi di _peggioramento_: decadimento, degrado, deterioramento, scadimento, regresso

Answer (score 1):

Se per *innovazione* si intende in generale una novità che cambia una situazione in modo da portare un miglioramento allora si potrebbero usare i sinonimi di *[peggioramento](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/peggioramento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)*: decadimento, degrado, deterioramento, scadimento, regresso.

In tutti questi casi avviene un'innovazione o cambiamento della situazione ma in peggio.

Aggiungo anche il termine *involuzione*, come saggiamente suggerito da @RiccardoDeContardi.

Comment: anche "involuzione" forse.